# Stuck on a Geometry Problem (II)

Tags: euclidean-geometry

(Looking for a geometric solution.)

$ABCD$ is quadrilateral, where $|AB|=|AD|=|DC|$. $AED$ is a triangle, where $E$ is the midpoint of $BC$. $\angle DAB=84 ^{\circ}$ and $\angle CDA=72 ^{\circ}$. Determine the measure of $\angle AED$.

[image]

Comment: You should include the trigonometric solution, as it could lead someone to a geometric approach without having to duplicate your effort.

Answer (score 0):

Using algebra in the complex plane we place A at (0,0), D at (1,0), B at (cos(84),sin(85)), C at (cos(180-72),sin(180-72)) relative to D, where the common length of the 3 sides is set to 1. Then we compute the position of E as the mean value of B and C, the direction from E to A by subtracting A and E and the direction from E to D by subtracting D from E. Then the angle phi is given by the argument (angle) obtained by dividing ED through AD. In Maple the computation reads:

Ap := 0+I*0 ;
Dp := 1+I*0 ;
Bp := cos(84*Pi/180)+I*sin(84*Pi/180) ;
Cp := Dp+cos((180-72)*Pi/180)+I*sin((180-72)*Pi/180) ;
Ep := (Bp+Cp)/2 ;
EAp := Ap-Ep ;
EDp := Dp-Ep ;
EAp/EDp/abs(EAp)*abs(EDp);
evalf(%) ;
argument(%)*180/Pi ;
evalf(%) ;

The result is 54 degrees.